# Alternatives to gap property

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm constructing a simple layout with a title and sub-title. When the two can be displayed on one line without the text wrapping, they should do so with a small amount of spacing between them. In all other cases, the title and sub-title should occupy 100% width. There should be no `margin-left` on the sub title.

I have created this using Flexbox and the `gap` property. It renders properly in Firefox:

[image: Render]

Here's the code:

```css
header {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Long title for the page itself</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</header>
<br />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shorter title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

Unfortunately, popular browsers such as Google Chrome have failed to implement support for `gap` used in conjunction with a `display: flex` layout.

Is there a way I can implement this using e.g. `display: inline-block` elements and negative margins such that it will work in legacy browsers like Chrome and Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `gap: .5rem`, use `margin-right: .5rem` on the `h1`.

```css
h1 {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: baseline;
}

header {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Long title for the page itself</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</header>
<br />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shorter title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This is fine, but I feel it will prematurely wrap. Ideally you want that margin-right to collapse into nothing if the h2 isn't on the same line

Comment: The `margin-right` method *does not* wrap prematurely any more than it does with the `gap` property. Put another way, there's no wrapping difference in either case. Tested in Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/1q3cgnmd/1/ @AdamWilliams